# C# .NET validate function doesn't effect both input fields

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, model-binding

So i'm currently working on a school project, for which you have to make a meal application. A meal has 3 courses, starter, main and dessert; from which starter and dessert are optional, but one has to be chosen. I wrote this function to check if one is 0 and the other is filled by a chosen object(StarterCourse & DessertCourse are integers):

```
public JsonResult CheckDessertCourse(MealCourse mealCourse)
    {
        if(mealCourse.StarterCourse == 0 && mealCourse.DessertCourse > 0)
        {
            return Json(true);
        }
        else if(mealCourse.StarterCourse > 0 && mealCourse.DessertCourse == 0)
        {
            return Json(true);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(false);
        }
    }
```

This is what my model looks like:

```
namespace EasyMeal.Models
{
    public class MealCourse
    {
        [Required]
        public int MealID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a date for this meal")]
        [Remote(action: "ValidateDate", controller: "Meals")]
        [UIHint("Date")]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the price for this meal")]
        [Range(0.01, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a positive price")] 
        public double Price { get; set; }
        [Remote(action: "CheckDessertCourse", controller: "Meals")]
        public int StarterCourse { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please choose a main dish for this meal")]
        public int MainCourse { get; set; }
        [Remote(action: "CheckDessertCourse", controller: "Meals")]
        public int DessertCourse { get; set; }
        public IList<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My view:

```
@model MealCourse
@using EasyMeal.Models.Logic

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create new meal</h1>
<div style="float: right; margin-top: -45px;">
    <a class="btn btn-danger pull-right" asp-controller="Meals" asp-action="Index">Cancel</a>
</div>
<hr />

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form asp-action="Create" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <span asp-validation-for="Date" class="text-danger"></span> <br />
                <label asp-for="Date" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Date" data-val="true" data-val-required="The date field is required." class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <span asp-validation-for="Price" class="text-danger"></span><br />
                <label asp-for="Price" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Price" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <span asp-validation-for="StarterCourse" class="text-danger"></span>
                <label class="control-label" asp-for="StarterCourse">Starter:</label>
                <select class="form-control" asp-for="StarterCourse" data-val="true">
                    <option value=0>Choose an option</option>
                    @foreach (var c in Model.Courses)
                    {
                        if (c.CourseType == "Starter" && c.Date <= GetDates.GetNextWeeksSunday() && c.Date >= GetDates.GetNextMonday())
                        {
                            <option value="@c.CourseID">@c.Name</option>
                        }
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" asp-for="MainCourse">Main Course:</label>
                <select class="form-control" asp-for="MainCourse">
                    <option value="">Choose an option</option>
                    @foreach (var c in Model.Courses)
                    {
                        if (c.CourseType == "Main" && c.Date <= GetDates.GetNextWeeksSunday() && c.Date >= GetDates.GetNextMonday())
                        {
                            <option value="@c.CourseID">@c.Name</option>
                        }
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <span asp-validation-for="DessertCourse" class="text-danger"></span>
                <label class="control-label" asp-for="DessertCourse">Dessert:</label>
                <select class="form-control" asp-for="DessertCourse" data-val="true">
                    <option value=0>Choose an option</option>
                    @foreach (var c in Model.Courses)
                    {
                        if (c.CourseType == "Dessert" && c.Date <= GetDates.GetNextWeeksSunday() && c.Date >= GetDates.GetNextMonday())
                        {
                            <option value="@c.CourseID">@c.Name</option>
                        }
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    <script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("input.input-validation-error")
                .closest(".form-group").addClass("has-danger");
        });
    </script>
}
```

I tried several things like adding more else if statements, i made a fake object for a Course. But still my application gives the error that when one isn't selected and the value should be 0...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When creating a meal, are you choosing both dessert and starter?

Comment: @HazardousGlitch One is left on "Choose an option" and the other one is selected from the dropdown list. Still it show the error that the one that is on "Choose an option" isn't valid.

Comment: Run it in debug mode and put a breakpoint at the if statement and see what values the object returned actually has.

Comment: @HazardousGlitch Done it several times, it returns the 0.. Still haven't figured it out

Comment: When you do the debugging and looking at dessert and starter, one of them is 0 and the other isn't? What is the other one?

Comment: @HazardousGlitch The other one has the CourseID value of the selected Course out of the dropdown list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206206/discussion-between-hazardousglitch-and-s-van-zanten).